# simplifying $\frac{15^4+105^2-225\cdot210}{130^2-50^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x=\frac{15^4+105^2-225\cdot210}{130^2-50^2}$

Since $225 = 15^2$ and $210 = 2\cdot105$ the numerator is $(15^2-105)^2$ which is $120^2 = 14400$.
The denominator is $(130-50)(130+50)$ which is $14400$. The answer is $1$. The solutions for the exam have proven to be wrong from time to time and in this case they state that $x=10$. This is wrong answer, or?

Comment: Trivial arithmetic:  $=1$.  What's the problem?

Comment: Another case of the problem being wrong. Very annoying.

Answer (score 4):

$\dfrac{15^4+105^2-225\cdot210}{130^2-50^2}=\dfrac{(15^2-105)^2}{(130+50)(130-50)}=\dfrac{120^2}{180\times80}=\dfrac{12^2}{18\times8}=1$

Comment: very sharp indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Your simplification works out (difference of squares). WolframAlpha calculates [the same](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2815%5E4%2B105%5E2-225*210%29%2F%28130%5E2-50%5E2%29), `=1` for verification.